# chat program - send doesn't work

Tags: python, send

I have made a chat program (in this moment only host can send messages):

server:

```
# server
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 150

server.bind((host, port))

print 'Server is open\nWaiting connections...'

server.listen(1)

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    while True:
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM:when i type messages and i send they , the client see only messages with a even number. why this happen?

```
        msg = raw_input('>>>')
        if msg == 'exit':
            client.send(msg)
            break
        else:
            client.send('<Host>' + msg)
client.close()
```

client:

```
# client
import socket
import time

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 150

client.connect((host,port))

while True:
    if client.recv(1024) == 'exit':
        print '<System>Host disconnected the Server...'
        print '<System>Program will shoot down in 5 seconds'
        time.sleep(5)
        break
    else:
        print client.recv(1024)
client.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'only sees messages with an even number'? I don't see any number involved in sending/receiving the messages.

Also, this doesn't seem like a very 'good' written server/client system. I recommend reading up on this topic by reading Beej's networking programming guide if you haven't done that already.

Comment: so if i send first message , client don't see anything ,  when i send second message client see it , when i send third message , client don't see it , etc... thank for read recommandation , isn't very good write because i'm at begining with networking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you receive the message *twice* in the client: First, you receive a message and check whether it's the "exit" message, then a *second* message is received and printed. Thus, only the even messages are printed, while the odd ones are used up in the `if` condition.

Try changing the client code to this:

```
while True:
    msg = client.recv(1024)
    if msg == 'exit':
        print '<System>Host disconnected the Server...'
        print '<System>Program will shut down in 5 seconds'
        time.sleep(5)
        break
    else:
        print msg
```

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't see that one. Would've probably made that mistake myself if I'd make something like that.